# Is it possible to migrate taxonomy terms when having only the term name?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, migrations

I'm starting to learn the migration module because i have to do quite a complicate migration from a Drupal 6 site to a Drupal 7 [Importing nodes with different field names from Drupal 6 to 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/123801/importing-nodes-with-different-field-names-from-drupal-6-to-7?noredirect=1#comment147713_123801)

And i'm wondering if it's possible to migrate taxonomy terms if you have only their name but not the tid (or better, the tid is different between the sites), and if it's possible how? (that is, other than making a query to load the tid from the db, i'd like to know if there's a more "automated" way)

Comment: You can, but you should find tin from older DB by name, but you will have problem if you have the same named term, you should resolve it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably will use [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module and [hook_feeds_presave](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!feeds!feeds.api.php/function/hook_feeds_presave/7) to manually re-import taxonomy name and reset the node associate your that taxonomy.